# Можно ли убрать индикатор окончания прокрутки в RecyclerView?

Tags: android, recyclerview

Можно ли убрать эту штуку, что бы в конце прокрутки список просто останавливался без всякой лишней индикации?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

В XML у RecyclerView добавьте

```
android:overScrollMode="never"
```